# Place objects in inline (display)

Tags: html, css

So, I want to put some stuff in an inline display through CSS but I am confused as to why it wont work. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div id = "allBody">
  <div id = "image">
    <img src = "https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/mafiagame/images/2/23/Unknown_Person.png/revision/latest?cb=20151119092211" id = "image">
  </div>
  <div id = "line"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#allBody {
  display: inline;
}
#image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
#line {
  height: 200px;
  width: 7.5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  background-color: cornflowerBlue;
}
```

What I want is to have them display next to each other. A working version of the code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/CyanCoding/he84kv8n/1/). Also, I am trying to follow a similar model to the email signature creator [here](https://www.hubspot.com/email-signature-generator#sig-generator-anchor) but after getting the things to line up and such, I am not trying to make them the same.

Here is an example of the kind of thing that I want it to look like (with a bit different styling wise):

[image: Example image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of what you're trying to make this look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to adding `display: inline` to `#allbody`, you also need to add it to both `#image` and `#line` (as those are siblings of one another that you wish to display inline). In addition to this, you'll also need `float: right` on the line to get it to the display on the right-hand side of the image:

```css
#allBody {
  display: inline-block;
}

#image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*padding-right: 30px; */ /* using padding distorts the image */
  margin-right: 30px; /* added */
  display: inline; /* added */
}

#line {
  height: 200px;
  width: 7.5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  background-color: cornflowerBlue;
  display: inline; /* added */
  float: right; /* added */
}
```

```html
<div id = "allBody">
  <div id = "image">
    <img src = "https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/mafiagame/images/2/23/Unknown_Person.png/revision/latest?cb=20151119092211" id = "image">
  </div>
  <div id = "line"></div>
</div>
```

I've also created a JSFiddle of this **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/h7trmxx8/)**.

Also note that you're probably looking for **`margin-right`** on the image, rather than `padding-right`. Using `margin-right` will offset the blue line, whereas `padding-right` will distort the circular profile picture.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to remove the DIV around the `img` tag - an image is inline  by default (BTW: You shouldn't have two elements with the same ID, that's invalid HTML), and add `display: inline-block;` to your `#line` element:

(And remove `inline` from the wrapping DIV `#allBody`)

```css
#image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
#line {
  height: 200px;
  width: 7.5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  background-color: cornflowerBlue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id = "allBody">
    <img src = "https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/mafiagame/images/2/23/Unknown_Person.png/revision/latest?cb=20151119092211" id = "image">
  <div id = "line"></div>
</div>
```